# deleted version are still being serverd in appspot.com

Tags: google-app-engine, version-control, python-2.7

I'm at lost as to why I have deleted some versions of my apps in appspot.com, but event after clearing out the cache on both local browsers and appspot.com under pagespeed service.

Old versions are still accessible. How long before deleted versions are gone?
Also, I have upload changes, but it does not show up at all.

So how long before changes show up?
If there is a way to force these to happen I would greatly appreciate it.
Thank you in advance of your assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Google's GSLB proxy will cache your static files for hours, even if you have disable your appspot application and then re-enable it.

My solution is to append version number at every css, js, jpg url.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the App Engine Admin page, you should be able to see all the instances you have running.  Kill all the instances for the old versions and it should stop serving.

Comment: Dear Dragonx
Thank you for your answer..this is what I have done.
1) Have deleted all other version except 1. (default)
2) Kill all instance including the default.
3) Clear out my browser cache, close the browser and relaunch the browser, go to website.. still no changes shows up.
4) going to old version 10.myapp.appspot.com .. still shows up..
any idea??

Comment: try http://garbage.mayapp.appspot.com.  It works right?  It's getting sent to your default version.  Probably your old version is no longer serving and you're getting your default version.  Can you verify that you're still seeing the contents of the old version?  That would be unexpected.

Comment: Dear Dragonx.. good morning to you and you are right.. it is sending the request to default version.. but still do not see the changes. this is Khan replicated site and I have changed some wordings in homepage.html, but some odd reason, it does not show the changes. if I download the files, i still see the changes that I have made, but it just does not show up in when rendered via website. I have not uploaded the original files but I'm currently an owner and able to download.. however, whatever changes that i have made, does not show. Thank YOU for your assistance in this matter

Comment: Most likely you aren't accessing the page you think you're accessing, but I can't really help you with that, you'll have to debug it on your own.